# URL Rewrite rules doesnt handle homepage / default page

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following URL Rewrite rules setup on my site

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(img|js|css|fonts)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

It works amazingly well, however I cant seem to get it to load the main page of the site unless its explicitly listed

`www.domainname.com/` & `www.domainname.com` doesn't work unless I explicitly write `www.domainname.com/index`.

Is there something I am missing in my pattern to allow for the default document to be served if no specific page is listed?

This is being handled by Helicon Ape, if that is of any interest to anyone or has any difference in the way it handles its rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mistake you are making here is using `*` quantifier. What it do is, captures `zero` or `more` occurrences of mentioned character.

Your regex: `^([^/]*)\/?$` Since you used `*` it will go lazy and match nothing. Rendering `.html` after replacement.

You can change regex to be greedy by using `+`. Your regex will be `^([^/]+)\/?$`.

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iV8nY9/1) notice that even blanks are matched because of lazy quantifier `*`.

Comment: thanks you so much, im stil gettng my feet wet when it comes to regex, and it solved my problem and makes more sense to me now

Comment: @user125264: Cool ! Am glad that worked though am not good with .htaccess and stuff.

Comment: FYI only, on mod-rewrite you dont need to escape the **/** as it's a dir or path seperater not a special char.